# Tests Failing in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm building an app while following a tutorial in the book [Simply Rails 2](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/rails2/) and am having trouble getting some tests to pass.

Here are the errors I'm receiving:

```
  1) Failure:
test_should_show_index(StoriesControllerTest)
[/Users/ryanclark/Projects/shovell/test/functional/stories_controller_test.rb:8:in `test_should_show_index'
 /Users/ryanclark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/testing/default.rb:7:in `run']:
<nil> expected to not be nil.

  2) Failure:
test_should_show_navigation_menu(StoriesControllerTest)
[/Users/ryanclark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:297:in `assert_select'
 /Users/ryanclark/Projects/shovell/test/functional/stories_controller_test.rb:44:in `test_should_show_navigation_menu'
 /Users/ryanclark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/testing/default.rb:7:in `run']:
Expected at least 2 elements matching "#navigation li", found 3.
<false> is not true.

  3) Failure:
test_should_show_new_form(StoriesControllerTest)
[/Users/ryanclark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:297:in `assert_select'
 /Users/ryanclark/Projects/shovell/test/functional/stories_controller_test.rb:18:in `test_should_show_new_form'
 /Users/ryanclark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/testing/default.rb:7:in `run']:
Expected at least 3 elements matching "form p", found 4.
<false> is not true.
```

My project is on [Github](http://github.com/IAMRYO/shovell) and I would really appreciate a little insight if someone would take a look and help me out.

Also, I'm happy to provide more details and code, just trying to keep the post short.

Comment: Hey, Ryan, have you solved your issues? Was my answer useful?

Comment: Hey Alex, I've read your answer and everything makes sense. Not sure if the code in the book is off or these things are in there. I haven't had time to go through the code yet, but will definitely let you know what I find out. Want to check both my code and the book.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Failure 1:** In test 'test_should_show_index' at line 8 `assert_not_nil assigns(:stories)`.

You have no stores with 'votes_count >= 5' in your test database. Here is your fixture for Stories (stories.yml):

```
one:
  name: My shiny weblog 
  link: http://poocs.net
  user: patrick

two:
  name: SitePoint Forums
  link: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/
  user: patrick
```

All stories have default value for votes_count (it is 0, see db/schema.rb, line 20). You need at least one story to have votes_count >= 5, thus change fixture to something like this:

```
one:
  name: My shiny weblog 
  link: http://poocs.net
  user: patrick

two:
  name: SitePoint Forums
  link: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/
  user: patrick 
  votes_count: 5
```

**Failure 2:** In test 'test_should_show_navigation_menu' at line 44 `assert_select '#navigation li', 2`

Your navigation div has 3 child `<li>` tags instead of 2 expected (see application.html.erb):

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><%= link_to 'Front page stories', stories_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Upcoming stories', bin_stories_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Submit a new story!', new_story_path %></li>
</ul>
```

**Failure 3:** In test 'test_should_show_new_form' at line 18 `assert_select 'form p', :count => 3`.

Your form contains 4 `<p>` tags instead of 3 expected. You can find it inside your template for 'new' action method (new.html.erb):

```
<% form_for(@story) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <b>Name</b><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Link</b><br />
    <%= f.text_field :link %>
  </p>

    <p>
        description:<br />
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.